# Handling many short times series with exogenous variables simultaneously

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive

I am trying to find a solution to a problem, having a dataset with multiple short time series and exogenous variables.

Read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412276/how-to-handle-many-times-series-simultaneously), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109749/can-i-have-multiple-individuals-for-each-time-point-in-arima/109764), and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/418259/arimax-vs-regression-with-arima-errors). And many other resources. Still cannot find a clear answer if I can build any autoregressive model.

[Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ZeOnW2tjFcOiasSRlIZGUIuUconiprP/view?usp=sharing) characteristics:

- a large number of independent entities and 3 observations, annual
- one times series for each that I want to forecast forward 1-3 years (2020-2022)
- multiple covariates, some time series themselves some static
- I hypothesize that any predictive power of the covariates is similar across entities

Any ideas how to approach this? I did all possible research, but nothing working so far.

Comment: For the data provided, which variable do you want to forecast, and which variables are covariates? What is the value of the covariates for the future years? If you don't know that, there may be no point including them.

Comment: @RobHyndman, thanks for your reply! My value of covariates for the future years is unknown, but in our case we hypothesize there is value in including them. Ideally, our model should tell us which covariates are meaningful in this predictive sense and which are not. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only three observations per id, fitting an autoregressive model is going to be problematic. Even if you have only one lag, you are essentially losing 1/3 of your data.

This is really a longitudinal data problem. So I'd start there -- look at the literature on mixed effects models for example. You will need to account for the lack of independence of the observations -- multiple observations per person. Here is a simple model to start with that uses `Articles` and `Year` as covariates in modelling `Score`, with `Articles` having a random coefficient, and `Year` providing a fixed effect time trend. I'm not sure that this model makes any sense, because you haven't provided enough information about your data. But it at least shows some of the relevant modelling functions in R.

```r
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
download.file("https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=13ZeOnW2tjFcOiasSRlIZGUIuUconiprP&export=download",
              temp <- tempfile())
df <- readr::read_csv(temp) 
df$id <- as.character(df$id) 
fit <- lmer(Score ~ Year + (0 + Articles|id), data=df)
summary(fit)
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: Score ~ Year + (0 + Articles | id)
#>    Data: df
#> 
#> REML criterion at convergence: 117.6
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -1.3558 -0.6324 -0.1746  0.4885  1.6620 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name     Variance Std.Dev.
#>  id       Articles  29.19    5.403  
#>  Residual          221.28   14.875  
#> Number of obs: 15, groups:  id, 5
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value
#> (Intercept)  -706.763  10437.660  -0.068
#> Year            0.355      5.171   0.069
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>      (Intr)
#> Year -1.000
predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(Articles=5, id="1", Year=2020))
#>        1 
#> 9.426341
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your time and efforts! I greatly appreciate your help!